# Why PayPal Payment page shows different?

Tags: paypal

Please any one explain. why paypal payment page differ. See screenshot

I want button to be checkout as guest. How to change that instead of pay with debit or credit button

**URL LOOKS:** https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=

[image]

**URL LOOKS:** https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=

[image]

I tried both PayPal standard and express. but button not change to **CHECKOUT AS GUEST**

Comment: I think it's their new design - hermes - that they are pushing. Don't ask me why... I'm curious though if you resolved it? (Since contacting PayPal customer service is like throwing balls against the wall -- they all bounce back.)

Answer (score 0):

Its depend upon the payment mode you selected from different vendors and depends upon the country currency you are paying

Comment: Currency only differ but both are under country of Singapore. I think is not depend on currency.

Comment: are you paying for the same vendor or different vendors, different vendors will implement differently

Comment: Different vendor. I want button to be checkout as guest. How to change that instead of pay with debit or credit button

Comment: those are configurable buttons at paypal side, which you can configure